# AJAX Extensions to upload part of the webpage

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX Extensions to upload part of the webpage, a Listbox when triggered.

Instead of "usernames" it is printing out a multitude of "System.Data.DataRowView" after each tick.

ASPX:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server"></asp:ListBox><br />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
Try
    connStr = "connectionstring works"
    cmdStr = "SELECT [username] FROM [nregister] WHERE [onoffline]=@onoffline;"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onoffline", "on")
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ListBox1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    TextBox6.Text = "Who is Online: " & ex.ToString()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which field from the datasource to display:

```
<asp:ListBox DataTextField="username" ID="ListBox1" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: I do not want to printout just the usernames.  I want to printout the usernames that have the attribute of onoffline="on".

Comment: @noviscientia your query is taking care of it by passing parameter to WHERE clause. And it returns all those filtered usernames in "username" field. But listbox doesn't know which field to display, you have to point it to it.